# Using XSLT to create XSL-FO with nested bold/italic tags

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'm creating xslt file, which should convert my xml into xsl-fo.

XML is something like that:

```
<doc>
  <par>
    <point>
      <text>some text</text>
    </point>
  </par>
</doc>
```

Of course, there are many paragraphs and points in document. I would like to add possibility to format "some text", for example

```
<bold>bolded text</bold> and <italic>italic</italic>
```

Should give

```
<fo:block><fo:inline font-weight="bold">bolded text</fo:inline> and <fo:inline font-style="italic">italic</fo:inline>
```

Now I have quite simple xslt document, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="versionParam" select="'1.0'"/> 
  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="simpleA4" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" margin-left="2cm" margin-right="2cm">
          <fo:region-body margin="2cm"/>
          <fo:region-before margin="0.2cm" extent="1.5cm"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="simpleA4">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-region-before"  margin-right="1cm"> 
            <fo:block text-align="start" margin-top="0.2cm">
            <fo:block text-align="end" margin-top="0.2cm">
                Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="terminator"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="par/point"/>
          <fo:block id="terminator"/>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="point">
    <fo:block font-size="16pt" space-after="5mm">
        <xsl:value-of select="tresc"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Should I add another template (bold, italic)? How am I supposed to call it in "text" node?

I found some solution:

```
<xsl:template match="//bold">
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"></xsl:value-of>
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```

But it didn't work for me. Output xsl-fo dosn't contain any fo:inline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at this example. It clearly shows how to hanlde inline nodes.

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="doc">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:page-sequence>
                <fo:flow>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="par/point"/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="point">
        <fo:block font-size="16pt" space-after="5mm">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bold">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </fo:inline>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="italic">
        <fo:inline font-style="italic">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

given:

```
<doc>
    <par>
        <point>
            <text>some <bold>bold</bold></text>
        </point>
    </par>
    <par>
        <point>
            <text>some <italic>italic <bold>bolded</bold></italic></text>
        </point>
    </par>
</doc>
```

produces:

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:page-sequence>
      <fo:flow>
         <fo:block font-size="16pt" space-after="5mm">
            some <fo:inline font-weight="bold">bold</fo:inline>
               </fo:block>
         <fo:block font-size="16pt" space-after="5mm">
            some <fo:inline font-style="italic">italic <fo:inline font-weight="bold">bolded</fo:inline>
            </fo:inline>
               </fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: The `select="node()"` are redundant.  From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Applying-Template-Rules: "In the absence of a `select` attribute, the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction processes all of the children of the current node, including text nodes."