# XPATH/XSL terminology to text with nested nodes in a manner like how bold and italics are used in HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath, xpath-2.0

This question is similar:
[Using XSLT to create XSL-FO with nested bold/italic tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038895/using-xslt-to-create-xsl-fo-with-nested-bold-italic-tags)

However, I want to know if there is a way to handle (refer to) the text that is outside the nested element.  For instance, if I use this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="handle-emphasis" />
```

To "call" the following templates:

```
<xsl:template match="p/emphasis[@type='italic']" mode="handle-emphasis">
    <xsl:element name="i">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/emphasis[not(@type='italic')]" mode="handle-emphasis">
    <xsl:element name="b">
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />            
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p/br" mode="handle-emphasis">

    <xsl:element name="br" />
</xsl:template>
```

Then I am able to successfully handle some custom tags that are much like HTML bold and italic.  However, if I create a template that matches just "p", it doesn't seem that template is executed for the text that is 'outside' the 'bold' and 'italic' nodes.

I am probably missing something simple, but this is driving me nuts.  Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete code samples of XML input, XSLT code, result you want and the result you expect, then we are hopefully able to tell you how to change the code. As for your current code, I wonder why you don't write `<i>` instead of `<xsl:element name="i">` and why you don't keep processing up inside of your template by doing `<xsl:apply-templates mode="handle-emphasis"/>` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="text()" />`.

Comment: Agreeing with @Martin: it's difficult to understand what exactly you're trying to do, without examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you were wishing you had a template whose match pattern were `p/text()`.

Comment: Exactly!  I didn't think to try p/text().