# Using XSLT to create XSL-FO with inline tag for every text

Tags: html, xsl-fo

Based on the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038895/using-xslt-to-create-xsl-fo-with-nested-bold-italic-tags/26711425#26711425)

I'd like to convert this HTML

```
<doc>
  <par>
    <point>
      <text><bold>bolded text</bold> and <italic>italic</italic></text>
    </point>
  </par>
</doc>
```

and obtain :

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:inline font-weight="bold">bolded text</fo:inline>
    <fo:inline> and </fo:inline>
    <fo:inline font-style="italic">italic</fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

Note the difference with the solution provided in the link, i'd like to have every text in an fo:inline tag. In this example the string " and " is placed in an inline tag instead of the parent block tag.

How can i obtain this, please ?

Thank you for your help.

Gpo23

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add a template specifically matching `text()` that is a direct child of `text`.

```
<xsl:template match="text/text()">
    <fo:inline>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```