# xml xsl transform match tags in entire document

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I have xml document, which needs xsl(xsl-fo) transformation to be applied for pdf generation in child nodes containing specific tag, like "bold", "italic", etc. and these tags can appear anywhere in text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <QuoteNumber>Q_ML/0/137088123123</QuoteNumber>
  <QuotationType>Type of Quote</QuotationType>
  <Insured>Name of insured, its not me</Insured>
  <ProposalDate>10/10/2013</ProposalDate>
  <Jurisdiction>Worldwide <bold>(Excluding USA and Canada)</bold> unless specifically stated otherwise</Jurisdiction>
  <Insurer>Some stupid company</Insurer>
  <ProposalFormDate>10/10/2013</ProposalFormDate>
  <ValidUntil>31/10/2014</ValidUntil>
  <Date>19/02/2015</Date>
  <ProductType>ML</ProductType>
  <Region>AUS</Region>
  <NZStandardnPoorsText />
  <InsurancePeriodFrom>31/10/2014</InsurancePeriodFrom>
  <InsurancePeriodTo>31/10/2015</InsurancePeriodTo>
  <Premiums>
    <PremiumText>
      To comply with the <bold>General Insurance Code of Practice</bold>, we advise that the key factors that affect premiums are the type and size of the risk,
      along with industry and claims experience
    </PremiumText>
    <Premium>
      <Limit>1,000.00</Limit>
      <BasePremium>90.00</BasePremium>
      <GST>9.00</GST>
      <StampDuty>7.51</StampDuty>
      <AdminCharge>15.00</AdminCharge>
      <GSTOnAdminCharge>1.00</GSTOnAdminCharge>
      <BrokerFee>0.00</BrokerFee>
      <GSTOnBrokerFee>0.00</GSTOnBrokerFee>
      <Total>1,951.51</Total>
    </Premium>
    <Premium>
      <Limit>2,000.00</Limit>
      <BasePremium>75.00</BasePremium>
      <GST>7.50</GST>
      <StampDuty>5.62</StampDuty>
      <AdminCharge>10.00</AdminCharge>
      <GSTOnAdminCharge>15.00</GSTOnAdminCharge>
      <BrokerFee>0.00</BrokerFee>
      <GSTOnBrokerFee>0.00</GSTOnBrokerFee>
      <Total>2,413.12</Total>
    </Premium>
  </Premiums>
  <Conditions>
    <Condition>
      <ConditionNumber>1</ConditionNumber>
      <ConditionText>Once this quote expires and if you wish to place cover we may request a new proposal form, renewal declaration or no claims declaration and also  reserve the right to amend the quotation terms and conditions. Alternatively please obtain a new quotation via the Webrater should the risk be suitable.</ConditionText>
    </Condition>
    <Condition>
      <ConditionNumber>2</ConditionNumber>
      <ConditionText>In the event that the proposed insured becomes aware of a material change to the nature of the risk to be insured, or a claim, or facts or circumstances which may lead to a claim between the date of the application and the inception of the proposed insurance, we reserve our rights to amend or withdraw our terms.</ConditionText>
    </Condition>
    <Condition>
      <ConditionNumber>3</ConditionNumber>
      <ConditionText>This quotation together with any material submitted by you will be the basis of a contract should cover be bound by the Insurer and shall be deemed to be attached to and form part of the policy.</ConditionText>
    </Condition>
    <Condition>
      <ConditionNumber>4</ConditionNumber>
      <ConditionText>Credit terms are <bold>90 days</bold> payment from the date of inception of the policy.</ConditionText>
    </Condition>
  </Conditions>
  <OptionalExtensions>
    <EmptyOptionalExtensions>
      No optional extension to apply <bold>unless otherwise shown below</bold>
    </EmptyOptionalExtensions>
  </OptionalExtensions>
</root>
```

I have tried, applying very generic template(see last transform), but no luck

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
  <xsl:include href="../../Common.xslt"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-size="10pt">
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="all-pages" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm">
          <fo:region-body region-name="xsl-region-body" margin-top="2.4cm" margin-bottom="2.1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm" border="1pt solid black" />
          <fo:region-before region-name="xsl-region-before" extent="2cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm" />
          <fo:region-after region-name="xsl-region-after" extent="2.1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm" />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="all-pages">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"  font-family="Arial" disable-output-escaping="yes">
          <fo:table table-layout="fixed"  margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm"  cell-spacing="1" width="17cm" padding-bottom="0.5em">
            <fo:table-column column-width="3.3cm"/>
            <fo:table-column column-width="13.7cm"/>
            <fo:table-body>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="QuoteNumber" />
              <xsl:apply-templates select="Insured" />
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold"> LIMIT OF INDEMNITY  : </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                    Any one Claim and in the aggregate during the insurance period:
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                  <fo:table margin="0pt">
                    <fo:table-body width="100%">
                      <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                          <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                            (a)
                          </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm">
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                          <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                            $ <xsl:value-of select="Limit1" />
                          </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                      </fo:table-row>
                      <xsl:if test="Limit2">
                        <fo:table-row>
                          <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                              (b)
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm">
                          </fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                              $ <xsl:value-of select="Limit2" />
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Limit3">
                        <fo:table-row>
                          <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                              (c)
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm">
                          </fo:table-cell>
                          <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                              $ <xsl:value-of select="Limit3" />
                            </fo:block>
                          </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
                      </xsl:if>
                    </fo:table-body>
                  </fo:table>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                  <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold">
                    PERIOD OF INSURANCE :
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                  <fo:table>
                    <fo:table-body>
                      <fo:table-row>
                        <fo:table-cell   padding-right="2pt" text-align="left" width="20%">
                          <fo:block font-size="8pt" > From: </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell  padding-right="2pt"  text-align="left" width="35%">
                          <fo:block font-size="8pt"  >
                            <xsl:value-of select="InsurancePeriodFrom" />
                          </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell padding-left="8pt"   padding-right="2pt"  text-align="left" width="10%">
                          <fo:block font-size="8pt" > To: </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:table-cell text-align="left" width="35%">
                          <fo:block font-size="8pt"  >
                            <xsl:value-of select="InsurancePeriodTo" />
                          </fo:block>
                        </fo:table-cell>
                      </fo:table-row>
                    </fo:table-body>
                  </fo:table>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="Premiums" />
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" number-columns-spanned="2">
                  <fo:block font-size="8pt" padding-top="2pt"  font-weight="bold"> Schedule of Benefits: </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="OptionalExtensions" />
              <xsl:apply-templates select="ProposalDate" />
              <xsl:apply-templates select="ValidUntil" />
              <xsl:apply-templates select="PolicyWording" />
              <xsl:apply-templates select="Insurer" />
              <xsl:apply-templates select="Conditions" />
              <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" number-columns-spanned="2">
                  <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                    We trust this is in order, if you wish to discuss any part of this quote please do not hesitate to contact us.
                  </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
              </fo:table-row>
              <xsl:apply-templates select="Date" />
            </fo:table-body>
          </fo:table>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="QuoteNumber">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold"> QUOTATION NUMBER : </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Insured">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold"> INSURED : </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" font-weight="bold" wrap-option="wrap" hyphenate="true">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Premiums">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" padding-top="2pt"  font-weight="bold"> PREMIUMS : </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <xsl:if test="PremiumText != ''">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="PremiumText" />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Premium" />
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="PremiumText">
    <fo:table margin="0pt" width="100%">
      <fo:table-body  >
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell font-size="8pt" padding-top="2pt" number-columns-spanned="3">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
          </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Premium">
    <fo:table margin="0pt" width="10cm">
      <fo:table-body  >
        <fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="2cm">
            <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold">
              $<xsl:value-of select="Limit" />
            </fo:block>
          </fo:table-cell>
          <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm">
          </fo:table-cell>
          <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
            <fo:table margin="1pt 1pt 1pt 1pt" width="8cm">
              <fo:table-body >
                <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                      <xsl:value-of select="BasePremium" />
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">   Base Premium</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                      <xsl:value-of select="GST" />
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">   GST</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <xsl:if test="../../Region='AUS'">
                  <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="StampDuty" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt">   Stamp Duty</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="../../Region='AUS'">
                  <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="AdminCharge" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                        Service Fee
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                  <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="GSTOnAdminCharge" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt">
                        GST On Service Fee
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="ContractReviewInGST">
                  <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="ContractReviewInGST" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt">   Contract Review (inc GST)</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:if>
                <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                      <xsl:value-of select="BrokerFee" />
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">   Broker Fee</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                      <xsl:value-of select="GSTOnBrokerFee" />
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">   GST On Broker Fee</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                      <xsl:value-of select="Total" />
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                    <fo:block font-size="8pt">   TOTAL</fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <xsl:if test="AlternativeTotal">
                  <fo:table-row border="0.5pt solid black">
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" >
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="left"> $ </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt" text-align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="AlternativeTotal" />
                      </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" width="0.2cm" border-right-color="black" border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" >
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
                      <fo:block font-size="8pt">   Alternative Grand Total</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                  </fo:table-row>
                </xsl:if>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>
          </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
      </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Conditions">
    <xsl:if test="count(Condition)>0 ">
      <fo:table-row >
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" number-columns-spanned="2">
          <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold" keep-with-next.within-page="always"> Conditions </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>

      <fo:table-row >
        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" number-columns-spanned="2">
          <fo:list-block>

            <fo:list-item>
              <fo:list-item-label>  </fo:list-item-label>
            </fo:list-item>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="Condition" />

          </fo:list-block>
        </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Condition">
    <fo:list-item>
      <fo:list-item-label>
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="ConditionNumber" />.
        </fo:block>

      </fo:list-item-label>
      <fo:list-item-body>
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="ConditionText" />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:list-item-body>
    </fo:list-item>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ProposalDate">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold"> DATE OF PROPOSAL : </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ValidUntil">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold"> QUOTE VALID UNTIL : </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="PolicyWording">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold"> POLICY WORDING : </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Insurer">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold"> INSURER : </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Date">
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold"> DATE : </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
      <fo:table-cell padding="2pt">
        <fo:block font-size="8pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="bold">
    <fo:block font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold">
      <xsl:copy-of select="/"/>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Comment: You should list your whole stylesheet and the output you are receiving.

Comment: Please show us the XSL-FO markup you want to create for your input sample and the one you currently get, so that we know which result you want. Simply telling us "it doesn't seem to work" does not allow us to help.

Comment: The XSL you showed should work, so we need to see more of the stylesheet to to find out why it doesn't.

Comment: Please have a look at updated xml and xsl

Comment: While no one is going to rewrite all of this for you ... try this. You in many places use xsl:value-of .... why? You should do so *only* if your are interested in the exact value of (text)  that element/attribute. Instead use xsl:apply-templates and let it flow. Not to mention in the last (bold) template. xsl:copy-of? why? Just apply templates and make a template for all things.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038895/using-xslt-to-create-xsl-fo-with-nested-bold-italic-tags][1]

This solution worked for me :-)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038895/using-xslt-to-create-xsl-fo-with-nested-bold-italic-tags

Answer (score 0):

There's no way for us to give a specific answer without seeing the rest of your XSLT ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but what's happening is that the `bold` elements are never getting processed.

You need to make sure you apply templates (`xsl:apply-templates`) at any of the ancestor levels you might be overriding. Also, knowing how the [built-in templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) work will be helpful.

Here's an example of how this might look.

**XML Input**

```
<root>
    <first><inner>This is 1. <bold>important</bold>, so what</inner></first>
    <first><inner>This is 2. <bold>important</bold>, so what what</inner></first>
    <second><inner2>This is 3. <bold>important</bold>, so what</inner2></second>
    <third><inner3>This is 4. <bold>important</bold>, so what</inner3></third>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" 
                    page-width="8.5in" 
                    page-height="11in">
                    <fo:region-body margin="1in" 
                        margin-top="1.5in" 
                        margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"> 
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="inner|inner2|inner3">
        <fo:block>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="bold">
        <fo:inline font-weight="bold">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSL-FO Output**

```
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
   <fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:simple-page-master master-name="my-page" page-width="8.5in" page-height="11in">
         <fo:region-body margin="1in" margin-top="1.5in" margin-bottom="1.5in"/>
      </fo:simple-page-master>
   </fo:layout-master-set>
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="my-page">
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
         <fo:block>This is 1. <fo:inline font-weight="bold">important</fo:inline>, so what</fo:block>
         <fo:block>This is 2. <fo:inline font-weight="bold">important</fo:inline>, so what what</fo:block>
         <fo:block>This is 3. <fo:inline font-weight="bold">important</fo:inline>, so what</fo:block>
         <fo:block>This is 4. <fo:inline font-weight="bold">important</fo:inline>, so what</fo:block>
      </fo:flow>
   </fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

**Rendered PDF Output** (using FOP 1.1)

[image: Rendered PDF Output]